# Partial application of type synonyms

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families, partial-application, type-synonyms

I'm having trouble with unsaturated type synonyms in the following example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LiberalTypeSynonyms #-}

module TypeFamilyHackery where

data T k v a = T

type family CollectArgTypes arr where
  CollectArgTypes (a -> b) = (a, CollectArgTypes b)
  CollectArgTypes _ = ()

type family MapReturnType f t where
  MapReturnType f (a -> b) = a -> MapReturnType f b
  MapReturnType f r = f r

type MkT k v = T k v v

-- | Goal:
-- @
--   BuryT Int = T () Int Int
--   BuryT (Bool -> Int) = Bool -> T (Bool, ()) Int Int
--   BuryT (a -> b -> c) = a -> b -> T (a,(b,())) c c
-- @
type BuryT t = MapReturnType (MkT (CollectArgTypes t)) t
```

But this complains with `The type synonym 'MkT' should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1`. I could specialize `MapReturnType` for `MkT (CollectArgTypes t)`, but I rather like it how it is.

Since `-XLiberalTypeSynonyms` doesn't seem to deliver (why?), what are my options to get `BuryT` working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LiberalTypeSynonyms` works by inlining all “obvious” type definitions. To make your example work, it would have to

1. Treat `MapReturnType (MkT (CollectArgTypes t)) t` first as some `MapReturnType ㄊ t`
2. Inline this to `ㄊ t`, using the definition `MapReturnType f r = f r`
3. At this point, invoking `ㄊ` again would give `MkT (CollectArgTypes t) t` which is a perfectly fine fully-applied synonym and hence no problem.

But step 2 isn't possible, because `MapReturnType` is *not* just a synonym. To use `MapReturnType f r = f r`, the compiler would first have to be sure that `r` isn't a function type, but it really can't know this – it's after all a completely free parameter.

So what the compiler would actually need to do there is, defer the resolution of `MapReturnType` and thus also of `BuryT` to concrete use sites. Now, that might be quite useful, but it would open up quite a can of worms. Namely, it would then be very easy to intertwine Turing-complete programs anywhere in the types of your program. I don't think this is worth it.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm stuck with specializing `MapReturnType` to `MkT`, aren't I?